# How to set up PayPal's two-factor authentication with a mobile app or trust my computer?

Tags: security, authentication, paypal

I just set up *two-factor authentication* feature for my account with PayPal, but I can't seem to find a way how to set it up to either trust my desktop computer (so that it doesn't ask for a PIN on it) or how to set it up to work with the [Google Authenticator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-authenticator/id388497605?mt=8) smartphone app to generate security PINs. Any ideas?

PS. At the current moment I was able to set it up to text security codes for me. The issue is that I have a limited allowance on text messages each month, so my carrier will start charging me for those at some point. So it'd be nice to avoid this. Plus waiting for a text message, that may take some time to arrive, is also inconvenient.

Comment: Firsts I don't believe you can setup it to work with Google Authenticator.  Second setting up a trusted computer would greatly reduce the security of 2-factor authentication.  Its not a require element of 2-factor authentication most people don't implement it

Comment: @Ramhound: Actually most other sites I use, do: Gmail, Hotmail, Dropbox, Lastpass, etc.

Comment: My point was that its still optional.

Comment: As a follow up -- I tried contacting PayPal about it and, as I expected, it fell on the deaf ears. Too bad that they don't care about providing better security for their customers...

Answer (score 1):

It can not be done with Google Authenticator or Authy app. Now I only saw two options with paypal

[you can see information here](https://www.paypal.com/au/securitykey)

> The Security Key is available in 2 versions:
>
> **Security Key card**: This is an electronic device that creates a unique security code instantly at the press of a button. It is the size of a credit card.
>
> **Mobile phone Security Key**: You can sign up to receive security codes by text message.
>
> A Security Key card currently costs $32.95 AUD. Additional or replacement cards are the same price.

Activate
Security Key: https://www.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_setup-security-key

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal Security Key page is still available at https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_security-token even though the account security page no longer links there. It can be used to manage SMS numbers, [Symantec VIP](https://idprotect.vip.symantec.com/) app tokens, and (presumably) the hardware security tokens PayPal used to sell.

There is also [a third-party Python script to fetch standard OATH TOTP keys from the Symantec VIP service](https://github.com/cyrozap/python-vipaccess) which can then be imported into Google Authenticator or another TOTP app. (Apparently these keys expire after about three years, so make sure you keep your SMS number up-to-date as a backup, and consider setting a reminder in your preferred calendar app.)